# How to create a user and set permission only to some folders on ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, openssl

I need to create a user and only allow access to some folders on my server. The user also needs to be able to create an SSL Key with the command:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out server.csr
```

I know it is possible to do but I don't know how. Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is too broad. Is the user going to login via GUI or using SSH? Creating a user is going to give him access to a lot of directories. Do you need to give the user access to other directories? Do you need multiple user to access those directories too?

Comment: well i need to create a user and this user can only access 2 directories, maybe if i create a group and put this user on this group

Answer (score 2):

You could create a group named `opssl`

```
# groupadd opssl
```

Now you can give access to that group:

```
# chgrp opssl /dir/folder1
# chgrp opssl /dir/folder2
# chmod g+w /dir/folder1
# chmod g+w /dir/folder2
# chmod o-rwx /dir/folder1
# chmod o-rwx /dir/folder2
```

Fist two commands set group ownership, the second pair gives the group write permission, and the third group removes access to anyone but owner and group.

Then create users within this group:

```
# useradd --gid opssl user1
# useradd --gid opssl user2
```

NOTE: this will give them access to those directories. Besides that, these users are like any other user you create there.